# First movie with Iron Man like HUD

Tags: first-appearance

What was the first movie that had a mecha or armored suit with a HUD like the one in Iron Man's suit?

Answer (score 2):

Fighter pilots first used HUDs in the 1950's to display altitude, speed and targeting systems on the front of the cockpit canopy.  So, it'd be difficult to imagine any film before that time period would have any kind of HUD.  Not only was it not a widely known technology, but the special effects would have been impractical and costly.

The first movie I can think of that used HUD was [The Terminator (1984)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terminator).  If anyone can think of one earlier, I'll be glad to delete my answer.

Comment: I'm asking for those that are shown to the audience as if they were materialized out of thin air in front of the pilot face.

Comment: I believe that [Firefox](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083943) (1982) beat that but I wouldn't bet much that was the earliest either.

Comment: @rraallvv - You understand that Iron Man's HUD doesn't "materialize out of thin air", right?  The HUD is shown against the inside of his face shield.  HUDs are usually projected on something (whether that be Iron Man's shield or Terminator's iris), not hanging in mid-air.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I don't see how is that relevant to my question. I think It could be easily accomplished by showing a different image in augmented reality on each eye's visor in the suit helmet, but I'm asking about the visual effect that is shown to the audience.

Comment: You asked for a movie with a HUD like Iron Man's.  It's **very** relevant to the question because Iron Man's HUD was projected on his visor.  You may want to update your question to specify that you're looking for movies where the visual effect is shown to the audience.