# First in-helmet shots (like Iron Man)

Tags: first-appearance, cinematography

(I am aware of [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34378/first-movie-with-iron-man-like-hud), but the question didn't word its request properly and as a result didn't get the desired answer)

In [Iron Man (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/), a common shot is used to let Robert Downey Jr. act while Tony Stark is in the suit. This one:

[image: Iron Man's interior HUD]

Unlike many HUD shots, this isn't a POV shot looking at his viewpoint. It takes some liberty with reality to achieve its purpose in a unique and effective way.

Did Iron Man pioneer this technique, or are there other films that previously used the effect?

**Specific Criteria:**

- The camera must be "in" the helmet. Close-ups of a character's face while they're wearing a helmet or mask don't count.
- By extension, the shot should be "impossible". If there's room inside the helmet for a camera (somehow), it doesn't count. Technically, interior shots in [Pacific Rim](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663662/) are shots from "inside" a "helmet", but the helmet is so big the effect isn't the same.

Comment: I know ['Sunshine'(2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/) used many 'in helmet' shots. But, I'm sure there are movies even before Sunshine that used those types of shots.

Comment: `Close-ups of a character's face while they're wearing a helmet or mask don't count.` Well, there goes Dragon Ball Z. Though there may be a Dragon Ball example.

Answer (score 7):

Not quite "in helmet", but pretty close shots were in *2001: A Space Odyssey* (1968). Not sure if it's really the first one though.

[A "beyond infinity" scene, for example.](https://youtu.be/ou6JNQwPWE0) I think there were few more scenes during Dave's conversation/'battle' with Hal, but I'm not sure.

For example ([0:40](https://youtu.be/ou6JNQwPWE0?t=40s) in linked video):

[image]

Comment: It's close! It's not *quite* what I'm looking for so I'll edit the question to clarify, but the shot is close enough to the Iron Man one that I think this answer should stick around, even if I don't accept it.

Comment: This is just a close-up of an actor wearing a helmet, almost completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

In lieu of an older film example, I looked into the [Sunshine (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448134/) example. This screencap is very close to what I'm looking for (although it doesn't *quite* fulfill criteria 2) so I'll post it as an example. I expect there were films that did this even earlier though.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Star Kid 1998. It won’t let me upload the picture but you can check out the trailer on youtube